# ArrayList Items inside of ArrayList Gets Repeated

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I'm making a GUI that stores the products (ArrayList) and the product items(ArrayList) of each product. However when I save, the Arraylist Items are changed and the recently saved item is getting repeated through out the whole ArrayList.

I expected the output to be (on second save):

```
[[1, TEST1, TEST1, TEST1, TEST1, TEST1, 2021-02-27], [2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, 2021-02-27]]
```

but instead it was:

```
[[2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, 2021-02-27], [2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, TEST2, 2021-02-27]]
```

Is there something I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

My Code:

```
package prog2exer1;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Products extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 
          Date currentDate = new Date();
          DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          String strDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
          ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> contentItems = new ArrayList();
          ArrayList<String> contents = new ArrayList();
          int id = 1;

    public Products() {
        initComponents();
        dateReceieved.setText(strDate);
        pID.setText(Integer.toString(id));
        DefaultTableModel tblmodel = (DefaultTableModel) products.getModel();
        tblmodel.setRowCount(0);
    }

  
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        pType = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        pDesc = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        pSupplier = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        quantityTrue = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        pCost = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        dateReceieved = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        plusSign = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        quantityAdd = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        products = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        newProduct = new javax.swing.JButton();
        stockIn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Product ID");

        jLabel2.setText("Product Type");

        jLabel3.setText("Product Description");

        jLabel4.setText("Supplier");

        jLabel6.setText("Quantity");

        jLabel7.setText("Total Cost");

        jLabel8.setText("Date Received");

        pID.setEditable(false);

        dateReceieved.setEditable(false);

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("New Products Stock-in");

        plusSign.setText("+");

        products.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "pType", "pDesc", "Supplier", "Total Quantity", "Orders"
            }
        ));
        products.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        products.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
        products.setName(""); // NOI18N
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(products);
        products.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 735, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 228, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(193, 193, 193))
        );

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "PType", "PDesc", "Supplier", "Quantity", "Cost", "Date Received", "Orders"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 721, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 411, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        newProduct.setText("New Product");
        newProduct.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                newProductActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        stockIn.setText("Stock In");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(quantityTrue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(plusSign, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(quantityAdd))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(pDesc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(pCost))
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(pSupplier, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(pType))
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(pID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                            .addComponent(dateReceieved)))
                                    .addComponent(stockIn)
                                    .addComponent(newProduct))
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(83, 83, 83)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)))
                .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(pID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(pType))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(pDesc))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(pSupplier))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(quantityTrue)
                            .addComponent(plusSign, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(quantityAdd))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(pCost))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addComponent(dateReceieved))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(newProduct)
                        .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                        .addComponent(stockIn)
                        .addGap(560, 560, 560))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 240, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void newProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        DefaultTableModel tblmodel = (DefaultTableModel) products.getModel();
        
        contents.clear();
        
        contents.add(pID.getText());
        contents.add(pType.getText());
        contents.add(pDesc.getText());
        contents.add(pSupplier.getText());
        contents.add(quantityTrue.getText());
        contents.add(pCost.getText());
        contents.add(strDate);
                
        contentItems.add(contents);
        
        System.out.println(contents);
        System.out.println(contentItems);
        
        pID.setText(Integer.toString(id));
       id++;
       
    }                                          


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Products().setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField dateReceieved;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JButton newProduct;
    private javax.swing.JTextField pCost;
    private javax.swing.JTextField pDesc;
    private javax.swing.JTextField pID;
    private javax.swing.JTextField pSupplier;
    private javax.swing.JTextField pType;
    private javax.swing.JLabel plusSign;
    private javax.swing.JTable products;
    private javax.swing.JTextField quantityAdd;
    private javax.swing.JTextField quantityTrue;
    private javax.swing.JButton stockIn;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

Comment: You can't add a new product by clearing the existing `contents` array, filling it with the new contents, and adding it to `contentItems`.  You must make a new `ArrayList<String>` array for every item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clearing contents in newProductActionPerformed create new content list:

```
 private void newProductActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        DefaultTableModel tblmodel = (DefaultTableModel) products.getModel();
        
        contents.clear(); // wrong, you are using same content object...
        contents = new ArrayList();// create new object for each content
```